# android adb memory decrease after deleting app?

Tags: android, adb

in my android device, im deleting some preinstalled apps via adb

first I check the memory size

> cat /proc/meminfo

With response:

```
MemTotal:         432984 kB
MemFree:           14444 kB
MemAvailable:     127944 kB
```

Then delete some app

> pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.launcher3

check memory size again, and get

```
MemTotal:         432984 kB
MemFree:           10944 kB
MemAvailable:     124728 kB
```

Why is the available memory being reduced after deleting app?

Im I checking memory available wrong?

Is there a "recycle bin" I need to clean?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meminfo is RAM.  Deleting apps will free up storage (disk space).  The two are unrelated.  Free memory wnet down because some app, possibly the part of the system that deletes apps, used it.